# 8086 assembly, about the PTR operator

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

this might be simple and silly but i'll ask it anyway since i don't seem to be able to figure it out.

a simple code snippet:

```
 assume cs:code, ds:data
 data segment
    b dd 256
 data ends

 code segment
 start:
        mov ax,data
        mov ds,ax
        mov ax,word ptr b     -> the result of this operation will be ax:= 256 (100h)

        mov bx,word ptr b+1   -> while this is going to be bx:= 1
```

I suppose it has something to do with the address and it being moved by a byte or something but i'm not exactly sure, and i really need to understand.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: this is the same as pointer dereference in C

Comment: I'm sorry for being vague. My question is why bx:= 1 ? since the contents of b are 256 , and b+1 would be 257 ? considering that mov should process the contents and not the address. Why does mov bx,word ptr b+1 result in bx:= 1 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This

```
mov ax,word ptr b
```

is easier to understand when formatted like this:

```
mov ax, word ptr [b]
```

which has effect of copying a word at address `b` into ax. So this

```
mov bx,word ptr b+1
```

is in fact

```
mov bx,word ptr [b+1]
```

which has effect of copying a word at address `b+1` into bx.

Now `dd` instructs to allocate a dword and assign 256 to it. 256 in hex is represented as `00000100h`. The dword will be allocated in memory like this `00010000h` - bytes `00h`, `01h`, `00h`, `00h` because on x86 lower bytes are stored at lower addresses (so-called little endian).

When memory is being read into registers bytes order is changed such that lower bytes occupy lower bits in the register ("natural", so-called big endian). So `00h`, `01h` in memory is turned into `0100h` inside a register and `01h`, `00h` in memory is turned into `0001h` inside register.

So the first `mov` gets the first two bytes from `b` (`00h`, `01h`) and makes `ax`==`0100h` and the second one gets the middle two bytes from `b` (`01h`, `00h`) and makes `bx`==`0001h`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the number of bytes only if we want to write an immediate value to a ram location.
Otherwise our assembler use the registersize for to determine how many bytes we want to access.

Except for using a dword access with using MASM, then we need also the declaration of DWORD PTR, if we want a dword access, example writing the content of EAX to a ram location, or reading a dword from a ram location into EAX. Same with all other 32 Bit-Register.

I think it is better to declare a named ram location with the define bytes(DB) notation, if we want a multiple access with a byte, word, and/or dword access.

```
b DB 0, 1, 0, 0
```

The registersize is well known and we do not need to specify:

```
mov al, [b]
mov [b], al

mov bl, [b+1]
mov [b+1], bl

mov ax, [b]
mov [b], ax

mov bx, [b+1]
mov [b+1], bx
```

Except for MASM:

```
mov eax, dword ptr[b]
mov dword ptr[b], eax
```

Using imediate values:

```
mov byte ptr[b], 0
mov word ptr[b], 256
mov dword ptr[b], 256
```

Dirk